# Как поместить результат sql-запроса в одномерный массив?

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте!)
У меня есть sql-запрос, который выводит столбец таблицы отсортированный по условиям..

```
$s = "SELECT square  FROM reports WHERE username = '$str' and
data LIKE '%$time' ORDER BY data;";
$r =  mysql_query( $s );
```

Надо поместить результат в одномерный массив..

square
    300 
    700 
    800 
    500

Comment: немного исправила

Comment: @Анна - вы здесь не причем :)

Comment: по вопросу не подскажете?)

Comment: @Анна, проверьте:

    print_r($squares);

Comment: @Анна - как вы поняли что он не пустой? И для отладки используют print_r или var_dump, кстати - откуда эта мифическая 3-ойка?

Comment: в самом деле..запрос не работал из-за кодировки..
спасибо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = "SELECT square  FROM reports WHERE username = '$str' and
data LIKE '%$time' ORDER BY data;";
$r =  mysql_query( $s );
$squares = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $r ) ) {
  $squares[] = $row['square']
}
```

Comment: не работает..
запрос выполняется правильно..но в массив ничего не заносится..

Comment: Проверьте **print_r($squares);**.

Comment: Вы уверены в том, что результат выборки не пустой? Лично я уверен в том, что он пустой :)